# How is Zenpou Hiyaku Ukemi taught in Shodokan Aikido?

Tags: aikido

Zenpou Hiyaku Ukemi (前方飛躍受け身) is a break fall technique in Aikido.

[image]

[Video (in English)](https://youtu.be/fOnAgnOU5wQ) and [video (in Japanese)](https://youtu.be/E_fRh0j7Muw) show how Zenpou Hiyaku Ukemi is taught in Yoshinkan Aikido.

## Question

How is this technique taught in Shodokan Aikido? I couldn't find any videos to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zenpou Hiyaku Ukemi is a tobu ukemi without tori.

## Tobu ukemi (Flip) 飛び受け身

Tobu ukemi is nothing but a forward roll (Zempo kaiten ukemi) where tori holds uke's hand.

### See saw

One leg forward, same arm bent so the palm is upwards. Point your head to the floor and move the back leg up making sure your back is straight. There is no roll, just a see-saw motion. Make sure your shoulder are straight and not side on.

### Flip

Sit on all fours, present one arm underneath your body (to the opposite side), and let your partner grab it.  Whoever grabs the arm has their legs bent and a straight back. Then, they pull the arm up, causing you to flip on your side. Thus landing in the perfect position. Note that your free arm should be hitting the matt first.

### Belt roll

Your partner is standing up, you are grabbing their belt knot with your hand palm up. Do the same exercise as the see saw above twice and flip on the third.

Try putting your head straight down in a line, your legs should arc over your body.

The first bit to hit the matt should be your free hand.

Once this step is comfortable, your partner puts your wrist in kote-gaeshi and you do the flip.

### Zempo kaiten → tobu

Your partner kneels on the floor, you execute a zempo kaiten roll. From time to time, your parter grab your front arm and a tobu ukemi occurs naturally.

### No partner

Start with the see-saw, then roll.

Comment: Not that I know off. You might find photos in [Scott's book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Aikido-Randori-Reconciliation-Opposing-Forces/dp/1861264984/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1485186731&sr=8-1&keywords=scott+allbright) but to be honest, I do not remember if there are some.

Comment: Found [this one](https://youtu.be/d2GrsliD4rQ?t=518), but I will not judge it for Aikido purposes, as in Judo, we learn it from and for different movements. I find the back arm a bit strange, but the staying straight (no turning/twisting) is something I find important.

Answer (score -2):

I am neither a shodokan practicioner nor a yoshinkan one, I am at Aikikai's line. But one thing i have notice is that this falling has many many names. Here in Brazil we call it Yoko Ukemi. But i have seen people calling it Leaf Ukemi, Neko Ukemi and so on... So maybe if you search with another name you can find what you want.